# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () Ionic 3 android

Tags: android, http, ionic3, httpclient

I'm working in **Ionic 3 platform Android** and **HttpClient**. I'm sending **post request** to server. It gives me error.

[image]

It is working on Postman.

Here's my code:

```
getAuthHeaders(auth: boolean = true) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (auth) {
      // headers.append('x-access-token', this.getTokenLocal());
    }
    // headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    return { headers: headers, withCredentials: true };
  }

  postLoginData(loginData)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.postLoginDataURL, loginData, this.getAuthHeaders()).map(res => res as any);
  }
```

Comment: i have error like you. any solution?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi use ionic http plugin...

Comment: Do you mean http instead of httpclient plugin?

Comment: http-advance-plugin